# Migrating existing Windows service to Service Fabric

Tags: c#, service, registry, microservices, azure-service-fabric

Recently, I have encountered an issue where I want to make my existing Windows service to run in a SF cluster.
However, this service does some registry operations, and it is dependent on it.

At SF, this is meaningless (as the service can be shutdown and re-run on another node). What are my options to make a smooth transition?
Use DB instead of a registry? Any other ideas (as in some cases the service stores data in the registry in case an error will occur in DB)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just create a [Stateful service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-introduction) for this. The Service would store the (registry) values in a [reliable dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-work-with-reliable-collections). This way the state would always be available to the service.

Comment: Very nice idea. I was so sure in my mind in Stateless service, that I have totally forgot about Stateful service. I'll look into it. Thanks!